# Can I create variable names for a series of values in a loop in Java?

Tags: java

I am creating a program that keeps tracks of vehicles in an intersection and controls their accelerations to avoid collisions. I am trying to create empty arrays to keep track of their vectors, and I need specific variable names for each vehicle in each lane. There are 8 lanes and a dynamic amount of vehicles in each lane. Here is a simplified version of what I have attempted to do:

```
int[] lane_veh_num = new int[]{lane_1_num, lane_2_num, lane_3_num, lane_4_num, lane_5_num, lane_6_num, lane_7_num, lane_8_num};
//lane_1_num, lane_2_num etc. are integers containing the amount of vehicles in each lane

for (int lane = 0; lane < 8; lane++){
     for (int veh = 0; veh < lane_veh_num[lane]; veh++){
          String vector_name = Integer.toString(lane+1) + "_" + Integer.toString(veh+1); //1_1, 1_2, etc.
          int[][] vector_name = new int[t][4]; //t is perviously defined, 4 values in the vector

          }
     }
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Like you want, no. Nor should you ever need to; you can store them in a map, or better yet, encapsulate it properly in a class: you have vehicles, you have vectors, you have lanes, you have a road. (Where best to *put* some of this information is always up for lively discussion.)

Comment: Maybe you are going about it the wrong way. Consider creating a `Vehicle` class which has fields for vector data, and a `Lane` class that has a field of type `List<Vehicle>` and build on that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, nor would you ever need to.

Whenever you need to store multiples of something, what you need is a collection (List, Array, Map, Set, whatever), as has been pointed out by the comments. Which one is best suited depends on your purpose.

And I have no idea what your four values are, but they might be better suited in a class than in an array.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that, and there is no need for doing that. If you really want to create a "variable name" for each piece of data, you can kind of do so by using a map. HashMap<String, String>(or make the second part a collection if you have multiple pieces of data) name = new HashMap<>(); The key(The first string) can represent the variable name, and the second string is the data.